Searching for a film in which a guy goes into a shop and exchanges some kind of sayings with the shop owner repeatedly
We're searching a movie for over two years now and now I am came to the idea of posting it here. We have only one clue:
A guy comes into a shop or deli over and over and gets its newspaper in the morning. every time he comes there, him and the shop owner have some kind of competition about sayings, like "the apple doesn't fall far from the tree".

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

I think you might be remembering this scene from A Few Good Men (1992):

EXT. SIDEWALK STAND - NIGHT

           KAFFEE'S CAR

           as it drives along a street in the D.C. business district. 
           it's evening now and the windshield wipers are fighting 
           against a rain KAFFEE pulls over at his usual newsstand. He 
           hops out, leaving the lights flashing and the door open, and 
           runs to the stand.

                                 KAFFEE
                     Hey, Luther.

                                 LUTHER
                     Admiral, how's the big case goin'?

                                 KAFFEE
                     Nose to the grindstone.

                                 LUTHER
                     No flies on you.

                                 KAFFEE
                     A rolling stone gathers no moss.

                                 LUTHER
                     Yeah, well it ain't over til the fat 
                     lady sings.

                                 KAFFEE
                     Ain't that the truth. Catch you 
                     tomorrow.

